How to fix a flickering LED flashlight
I own a LED flashlight for 4 years but it started flickering recently.
The flashlight is rechargeable and has 2 modes, standard LED and COB LED.
The COB LED does not have the issue.
You can see the flashlight in action here :
https://photos.app.goo.gl/7d9J3brDAkSDHk246
It start flickering after 20 seconds of video. All electronic components are visible in the video, there is none under the PCB.
How can I proceed to find where is the defective component responsible for the flickering effect?

Newer LED flashlights may use boost circuits and/or constant current sources and may not dim when the batteries are weak. Some of mine will act squirrely when the batteries are weak. Your batteries may be failing.
